# WordPress database setup failure on FastHosts server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, webserver, hosting

I am trying as best I can to follow the setup instructions for WordPress, using a FastHosts hosting package.

*one click install, they said...it's easy, they said!*

I've entered by database details into the setup page correctly as specified by the instructions, and they I get this:

> Error establishing a database connection This either means that the
>   username and password information in your wp-config.php file is
>   incorrect or we can't contact the database server at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
>   This could mean your host's database server is down.
>
> Are you sure you have the correct username and password? Are you sure
>   that you have typed the correct hostname? Are you sure that the
>   database server is running? If you're unsure what these terms mean you
>   should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can
>   always visit the WordPress Support Forums.

Before you ask: yes, `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` points to a real IP address.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems the database details is not correct. I would recommend you to ask their support team to help you to install the wordpress. I believe to install wordpress only take 2 minutes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you install the database befor installing the Wordpress? It seems that the database is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have web scripting enabled for the domain you are trying to load WP on.

https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/1751/~/installing-wordpress-manually - (step 3)